# Adding 1 second to an existing datetime

Tags: python

In python3, I have a process where I want to add 1 second to a datetime.  The datetime is in the following format below and I'm not sure the best way on how to do that.

2021-09-30T13:53:05Z

Comment: `my_datetime += datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)`

Comment: Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("2021-09-30T13:53:05Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
>>> dt = dt + timedelta(seconds=1)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 30, 13, 53, 6)
```

This should work